# members of class being overwritten when new instance created c++/cli

Tags: .net, arrays, class, c++-cli, managed

I have tried to implement the following:

1) Create a class that contains managed arrays
2) Create three instances of this class
3) Fill those arrays from three different data files.
4) Perform an analysis of this data

I have been able to compile code that performs task numbers one and two, however when I fill the arrays of the subsequent instances they seem to overwrite the data of the previous ones. I have tried to use a structure instead of a class. I have tried to use native arrays instead of managed arrays. I am obviously missing something here, but I can't find my answer anywhere that I have looked. Maybe I don't know the terminology to ask my question correctly.

Also, when I used the debugger I found that the garbage collector seemed to delete my data before I could perform my analysis on it.

Any help would be appreciated.

The problem is that the class instance LowE is overwritten with MedE when the button to load the second file is pushed.

I tried to ask this question without posting the entire project code and was not successful So, here is what I have:

File runData.h

```
#pragma once

#define MAXPOINTS 1536
#define LDBL_MAX 1.7976931348623158e+308
#define MAXORDER 10
#define MAXVOLUME 100.0


using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Diagnostics;


namespace EDCCalApp02 {


 public ref class  runData //:  public System::ComponentModel::Component
{
public:

       static array<double^> ^WPcoefs  = gcnew array<double^>(MAXORDER+1);

        static array<double ^,2> ^fData1  = gcnew array<double^,2>(MAXPOINTS,7);

       static array<int^,2> ^iData1  = gcnew array<int^,2>(MAXPOINTS,7);

        static array<int^,2> ^DataSize  = gcnew array<int^,2>(3,3);


      int numLines; 
      int numCols;
      int indx;
      int drops;


    runData(void)
    {


         for (int n = 0; n<1536; n++) {

             fData1[n,0] = 0.0;
             iData1[n,5] = 0;
             iData1[n,6] = 0; 
         }


    }


private:

    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code

    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        components = gcnew System::ComponentModel::Container();
    }
#pragma endregion


};


}
```

File Form1.h

```
#pragma once

#define MAXPOINTS 1536
#define LDBL_MAX 1.7976931348623158e+308
#define MAXORDER 10
#define MAXVOLUME 100.0

#include "runData.h"
#include "Graph1.h"
#include "Global1.h"

namespace EDCCalApp02 {

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::IO;

array<double^> ^polyfit(array<double^,2> ^, int, int);
array<double^,2>  ^datasort(array<double^,2> ^, int);
double ldpow(  double , unsigned );
float poly_correlcoef( array<double^,2> ^ ,int, array<double^> ^, int  );
array<double^> ^get_xy_max_min( array<double^,2> ^ ,int );


array<double^,2> ^fillData(int,  array<double^> ^, runData ^ );
array<double^,2> ^makeCurve(array<double^,2> ^, array<double^,2> ^, array<double^,2> ^, double);
array<double^,2> ^makeCoefs(array<double^,2> ^, array<double^> ^);
runData  ^LoadData(array<String^> ^);

public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{
public:
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        int numLines = 0, numCols=0;


  try{
  System::IO::StreamReader ^ sr = gcnew
  System::IO::StreamReader("WellPlate Volume Definitions.txt");
  array<String^> ^lines= System::IO::File::ReadAllLines("WellPlate Volume Definitions.txt");

  numLines = lines->Length;
  array<String^> ^Header=lines[0]->Split(',');
  numCols = Header->Length;

  staVolFile = gcnew array<String^,2>(numLines,numCols);

  for(int i=1;i<numLines;i++) {

     array<String^> ^lineSplit=lines[i]->Split(',');

     for(int j=0;j<numCols;j++){
       staVolFile[i-1,j] = lineSplit[j];
       }

     cbx_WellPlateList->Items->Add(staVolFile[i-1,0]);
    }

         sr->Close();
  }
            catch(IOException ^)       {
    MessageBox::Show(L"WellPlate Volume Definitions.txt\n\n" 
        L"Was Not Read\n\n"
        L"Please Check the File\n"
        L"and Try Again");

        }

    }

protected:

    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  tbx_File1;
protected: 

protected: 
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  lbl_File1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox^  cbx_WellPlateList;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  tbx_File2;
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  tbx_File3;

private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  lbl_Volume;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  btn_Exit;

private:
public:

     array<String^,2>  ^staVolFile;
     static array<bool^> ^loaded = gcnew array<bool^>(4) {false,false,false,false};


    static  runData ^LowE = ( gcnew runData);
    static  runData ^MedE = ( gcnew runData);
    static  runData ^HighE = (gcnew runData);

private: System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog^  openFileDialog1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::SaveFileDialog^  saveFileDialog1;

    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code

    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(Form1::typeid));
        this->tbx_File1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->lbl_File1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->cbx_WellPlateList = (gcnew     System::Windows::Forms::ComboBox());

        this->btn_Exit = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->openFileDialog1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::OpenFileDialog());
        this->saveFileDialog1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::SaveFileDialog());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // tbx_File1
        // 
        this->tbx_File1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(40, 100);
        this->tbx_File1->Name = L"tbx_File1";
        this->tbx_File1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(267, 20);
        this->tbx_File1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->tbx_File1->Text = L"Enter .csv File 1";

        // cbx_WellPlateList
        // 
        this->cbx_WellPlateList->FormattingEnabled = true;
        this->cbx_WellPlateList->Location = System::Drawing::Point(40, 40);
        this->cbx_WellPlateList->Name = L"cbx_WellPlateList";
        this->cbx_WellPlateList->Size = System::Drawing::Size(221, 21);
        this->cbx_WellPlateList->TabIndex = 2;
        this->cbx_WellPlateList->SelectedIndexChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::cbx_WellPlateList_SelectedIndexChanged);


        this->btnFile1->AutoSizeMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoSizeMode::GrowAndShrink;
        this->btnFile1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(306, 98);
        this->btnFile1->Name = L"btnFile1";
        this->btnFile1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(25, 24);
        this->btnFile1->TabIndex = 7;
        this->btnFile1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->btnFile1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btnFile1_Click);

        // lbl_WellplateList
        // 
        this->lbl_WellplateList->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Top | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Bottom) 
            | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Left) 
            | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Right));
        this->lbl_WellplateList->AutoSize = true;
        this->lbl_WellplateList->Location = System::Drawing::Point(45, 25);
        this->lbl_WellplateList->Name = L"lbl_WellplateList";
        this->lbl_WellplateList->Size = System::Drawing::Size(98, 13);
        this->lbl_WellplateList->TabIndex = 28;
        this->lbl_WellplateList->Text = L"Wellplate Selection";
        // 
        // btn_Graph1
        // 
        this->btn_Graph1->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::White;
        this->btn_Graph1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(348, 99);
        this->btn_Graph1->Name = L"btn_Graph1";
        this->btn_Graph1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(38, 23);
        this->btn_Graph1->TabIndex = 29;
        this->btn_Graph1->Text = L"G1";
        this->btn_Graph1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->btn_Graph1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btn_Graph1_Click);

        // 
        // btn_Create
        // 
        this->btn_Create->Anchor = static_cast<System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles>((System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Bottom | System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Left));
        this->btn_Create->Location = System::Drawing::Point(40, 292);
        this->btn_Create->Name = L"btn_Create";
        this->btn_Create->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->btn_Create->TabIndex = 33;
        this->btn_Create->Text = L"Create Cal";
        this->btn_Create->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->btn_Create->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btn_Create_Click);


        this->btn_Exit->Anchor = System::Windows::Forms::AnchorStyles::Bottom;
        this->btn_Exit->Location = System::Drawing::Point(657, 304);
        this->btn_Exit->Name = L"btn_Exit";
        this->btn_Exit->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->btn_Exit->TabIndex = 36;
        this->btn_Exit->Text = L"Exit";
        this->btn_Exit->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->btn_Exit->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::btn_Exit_Click);

        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->BackColor = System::Drawing::Color::White;
        this->BackgroundImage = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^  >(resources->GetObject(L"$this.BackgroundImage")));
        this->BackgroundImageLayout = System::Windows::Forms::ImageLayout::Stretch;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(830, 348);
        this->Controls->Add(this->btn_Exit);
        this->Controls->Add(this->btn_Graph1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->lbl_WellplateList);

        this->Controls->Add(this->lbl_Order1);

        this->Controls->Add(this->lbl_Max1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->lbl_Min1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->tbx_Order1);


        this->Controls->Add(this->cbx_WellPlateList);
        this->Controls->Add(this->lbl_File1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->tbx_File1);
        this->Icon = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Icon^  >(resources->GetObject(L"$this.Icon")));
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"EDC Calibration App";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }
```

## pragma endregion

private: System::Void cbx_WellPlateList_SelectedIndexChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

```
          double WPcoefs[MAXORDER+1];// = gcnew array<double^>(MAXORDER+1);

          int selectedIndex = cbx_WellPlateList->SelectedIndex;

          for(int i=0; i <= MAXORDER; i++) WPcoefs[i]=0.0;


          for(int i=3;i<8;i++){

          WPcoefs[i-3] = double::Parse(staVolFile[selectedIndex,i]);
          }

          for(int i=0;i<MAXORDER+1;i++){
                LowE->WPcoefs[i] = WPcoefs[i];
                MedE->WPcoefs[i] = WPcoefs[i];
                HighE->WPcoefs[i] = WPcoefs[i];
          }
  loaded[0] = true;


      }

        private: System::Void btnFile1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {


    if(!*loaded[0]) {
        MessageBox::Show("Please select a plate and try again.");
        return;
    }
  try {     
     if(openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
  {
      System::IO::StreamReader ^ sr = gcnew
      System::IO::StreamReader(openFileDialog1->FileName);
```

if (!sr)
   {
      tbx_File1->Text = "Could not open file.";

}

```
 String^ FilePath = openFileDialog1->FileName;
  array<String^> ^File = FilePath->Split('\\');
     int  num = File->Length;
 tbx_File1->Text = File[num-1];

  array<String^> ^rawData1= System::IO::File::ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1->FileName);

  LowE =  LoadData(rawData1);


     loaded[1] = true;
     sr->Close(); 
     }

  }
            catch(IOException ^)
   {

    MessageBox::Show("File Not Read\n Please Check the File\n and Try Again");
    return;
            }   
                 }
```

private: System::Void btnFile2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

```
                if(!*loaded[0]) {
        MessageBox::Show("Please select a plate and try again.");
        return;
    }
  try {     
     if(openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
  {
      System::IO::StreamReader ^ sr = gcnew
      System::IO::StreamReader(openFileDialog1->FileName);
```

if (!sr)
   {
      tbx_File2->Text = "Could not open file.";

}

```
 String^ FilePath = openFileDialog1->FileName;
  array<String^> ^File = FilePath->Split('\\');
     int  num = File->Length;
 tbx_File2->Text = File[num-1];

  array<String^> ^rawData2= System::IO::File::ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1->FileName);


  MedE =   LoadData(rawData2);


     loaded[2] = true;
     sr->Close(); 
     }

  }
            catch(IOException ^)
   {

    MessageBox::Show("File Not Read\n Please Check the File\n and Try Again");
    return;
            }   


     }
```

private: System::Void btnFile3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

```
                if(!*loaded[0]) {
        MessageBox::Show("Please select a plate and try again.");
        return;
    }
  try {     
     if(openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK)
  {
      System::IO::StreamReader ^ sr = gcnew
      System::IO::StreamReader(openFileDialog1->FileName);
```

if (!sr)
   {
      tbx_File3->Text = "Could not open file.";

}

```
 String^ FilePath = openFileDialog1->FileName;
  array<String^> ^File = FilePath->Split('\\');
     int  num = File->Length;
 tbx_File3->Text = File[num-1];

  array<String^> ^rawData3= System::IO::File::ReadAllLines(openFileDialog1->FileName);


  HighE =     LoadData(rawData3);


     loaded[3] = true;
     sr->Close(); 
     }

  }
            catch(IOException ^)
   {

    MessageBox::Show("File Not Read\n Please Check the File\n and Try Again");
    return;
            }   


     }
```

private: System::Void btn_Exit_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

```
         this->Close();
     }
```

private: System::Void btn_Graph1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

```
         int Size = LowE->indx;

         if(Size > 3){
         array<double^,2> ^plotData =  gcnew array<double^,2>(Size,4);
         array<double^,2> ^fitData =  gcnew array<double^,2>(Size,2);
         double Min = Convert::ToDouble(tbx_Min1->Text);
         double Max = Convert::ToDouble(tbx_Max1->Text);
         int Ord = Convert::ToInt32(tbx_Order1->Text);
         double Vol;
         int count = 0;
         int iData;
         for(int i=1; i < Size-1 ; i++){
            if((*LowE->fData1[i,0] <= Max) && (*LowE->fData1[i,0] >= Min )){
                Vol = ((*LowE->fData1[i,6] / *LowE->iData1[i,4]));
                if(Vol > -1.0*MAXVOLUME && Vol < MAXVOLUME){
                    plotData[count,0] = *LowE->fData1[i,0];
                    fitData[count,0] = *plotData[count,0];
                    iData = (int) (100.0 * *plotData[count,0]);
                    plotData[count,0] = iData / 100.0;
                    plotData[count,1] = Vol;
                    fitData[count,1] = Vol;
                    count++;

                }
            }
         }
                array<double^> ^plotCoefs = gcnew array<double^>(MAXORDER +1);
                plotCoefs = polyfit(fitData,count-1,Ord);
                double Delta = (Max + 0.2)/count;

                plotData[0,2] = 0.0;

                for(int i=0; i < count; i++) {
                double LLOrd = 1.0;
                plotData[i,3] = 0.0;
                if(i>0) plotData[i,2] = *plotData[i-1,2] + Delta;
                 for(int k=0; k <= Ord; k++) {
                     plotData[i,3] = *plotData[i,3] +*plotCoefs[k] * LLOrd;
                     LLOrd = LLOrd * *plotData[i,2];
                 }

                }
                if(count > 2){
              Graph1^ plot1 = gcnew Graph1(count-1,plotData);

              plot1->ShowDialog();
                } else{
                            MessageBox::Show(" Not Enough Valid Data\n Please Check the File\n and Try Again");
                }
                } else{
                            MessageBox::Show(" File Does Not Contain Enough Data\n Please Check the File\n and Try Again");
                }

     }
```

private: System::Void btn_Graph2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

```
         int Size = MedE->indx;

         if(Size > 3){
         array<double^,2> ^plotData =  gcnew array<double^,2>(Size,4);
         array<double^,2> ^fitData =  gcnew array<double^,2>(Size,2);
         double Min = Convert::ToDouble(tbx_Min2->Text);
         double Max = Convert::ToDouble(tbx_Max2->Text);
         int Ord = Convert::ToInt32(tbx_Order2->Text);
         double Vol;
         int count = 0;
         int iData;
         for(int i=1; i < Size-1 ; i++){
            if((*MedE->fData1[i,0] <= Max) && (*MedE->fData1[i,0] >= Min )){
                Vol = ((*MedE->fData1[i,6] / *MedE->iData1[i,4]));
                if(Vol > -1.0*MAXVOLUME && Vol < MAXVOLUME){
                    plotData[count,0] = *MedE->fData1[i,0];
                    fitData[count,0] = *plotData[count,0];
                    iData = (int) (100.0 * *plotData[count,0]);
                    plotData[count,0] = iData / 100.0;
                    plotData[count,1] = Vol;
                    fitData[count,1] = Vol;
                    count++;

                }
            }
         }
                array<double^> ^plotCoefs = gcnew array<double^>(MAXORDER +1);
                plotCoefs = polyfit(fitData,count-1,Ord);
                double Delta = (Max + 0.2)/count;

                plotData[0,2] = 0.0;

                for(int i=0; i < count; i++) {
                double LLOrd = 1.0;
                plotData[i,3] = 0.0;
                if(i>0) plotData[i,2] = *plotData[i-1,2] + Delta;
                 for(int k=0; k <= Ord; k++) {
                     plotData[i,3] = *plotData[i,3] +*plotCoefs[k] * LLOrd;
                     LLOrd = LLOrd * *plotData[i,2];
                 }

                }
                if(count > 2){
              Graph1^ plot1 = gcnew Graph1(count-1,plotData);

              plot1->ShowDialog();
                } else{
                            MessageBox::Show(" Not Enough Valid Data\n Please Check the File\n and Try Again");
                }
                } else{
                            MessageBox::Show(" File Does Not Contain Enough Data\n Please Check the File\n and Try Again");
                }


     }
```

private: System::Void btn_Graph3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

```
         int Size = HighE->indx;

         if(Size > 3){
         array<double^,2> ^plotData =  gcnew array<double^,2>(Size,4);
         array<double^,2> ^fitData =  gcnew array<double^,2>(Size,2);
         double Min = Convert::ToDouble(tbx_Min3->Text);
         double Max = Convert::ToDouble(tbx_Max3->Text);
         int Ord = Convert::ToInt32(tbx_Order3->Text);
         double Vol;
         int count = 0;
         int iData;
         for(int i=1; i < Size-1 ; i++){
            if((*HighE->fData1[i,0] <= Max) && (*HighE->fData1[i,0] >= Min )){
                Vol = ((*HighE->fData1[i,6] / *HighE->iData1[i,4]));
                if(Vol > -1.0*MAXVOLUME && Vol < MAXVOLUME){
                    plotData[count,0] = *HighE->fData1[i,0];
                    fitData[count,0] = *plotData[count,0];
                    iData = (int) (100.0 * *plotData[count,0]);
                    plotData[count,0] = iData / 100.0;
                    plotData[count,1] = Vol;
                    fitData[count,1] = Vol;
                    count++;

                }
            }
         }
                array<double^> ^plotCoefs = gcnew array<double^>(MAXORDER +1);
                plotCoefs = polyfit(fitData,count-1,Ord);
                double Delta = (Max + 0.2)/count;

                plotData[0,2] = 0.0;

                for(int i=0; i < count; i++) {
                double LLOrd = 1.0;
                plotData[i,3] = 0.0;
                if(i>0) plotData[i,2] = *plotData[i-1,2] + Delta;
                 for(int k=0; k <= Ord; k++) {
                     plotData[i,3] = *plotData[i,3] +*plotCoefs[k] * LLOrd;
                     LLOrd = LLOrd * *plotData[i,2];
                 }

                }
                if(count > 2){
              Graph1^ plot1 = gcnew Graph1(count-1,plotData);

              plot1->ShowDialog();
                } else{
                            MessageBox::Show(" Not Enough Valid Data\n Please Check the File\n and Try Again");
                }
                } else{
                            MessageBox::Show(" File Does Not Contain Enough Data\n Please Check the File\n and Try Again");
                }



     }
```

private: System::Void btn_Create_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

```
             int i=0;

             array<double^> ^Args1 = gcnew array<double^>(6) {0.0,0.0,2.0,5.0,3.0,3.0};
             array<double^> ^Args2 = gcnew array<double^>(6) {0.0,0.0,2.0,5.0,3.0,3.0};
             array<double^> ^Args3 = gcnew array<double^>(6) {0.0,0.0,2.0,5.0,3.0,3.0};

             array<double^,2> ^Coefs1 = gcnew array<double^,2>(MAXORDER +4, 4);
             array<double^,2> ^Coefs2 = gcnew array<double^,2>(MAXORDER +4, 4);
             array<double^,2> ^Coefs3 = gcnew array<double^,2>(MAXORDER +4, 4);

             array<double^,2> ^Curve = gcnew array<double^,2>(36, 4);

             int minSz = LowE->indx;
             int midSz = MedE->indx;
             int maxSz = HighE->indx;


             double Vol = (Convert::ToDouble(tbx_Volume->Text));

                array<double^,2> ^minData,  ^medData, ^maxData;
                Args1[0] = (Convert::ToDouble(tbx_Min1->Text));
                Args1[1] = (Convert::ToDouble(tbx_Max1->Text));
                Args1[2] = (Convert::ToDouble(tbx_Order1->Text));

                minData = fillData(minSz, Args1, LowE);
                Coefs1 = makeCoefs(minData,Args1);

                Args2[0] = (Convert::ToDouble(tbx_Min2->Text));
                Args2[1] = (Convert::ToDouble(tbx_Max2->Text));
                Args2[2] = (Convert::ToDouble(tbx_Order2->Text));

                medData = fillData(minSz, Args2, MedE);
                Coefs2 = makeCoefs(medData,Args1);

                Args3[0] = (Convert::ToDouble(tbx_Min3->Text));
                Args3[1] = (Convert::ToDouble(tbx_Max3->Text));
                Args3[2] = (Convert::ToDouble(tbx_Order3->Text));

                maxData = fillData(minSz, Args3, HighE);
                Coefs3 = makeCoefs(maxData,Args1);

                Curve = makeCurve(Coefs1,Coefs2,Coefs3,Vol);


    array<String^,2> ^calFile = gcnew array<String^,2>(36,4);
    double tempDouble; 


   String ^myfile = "";
   saveFileDialog1->ShowDialog() ;
   myfile = saveFileDialog1->FileName;

   try  {

     FileStream ^outFile = gcnew FileStream(myfile, FileMode::Create, FileAccess::Write);
     StreamWriter ^streamOut = gcnew StreamWriter(outFile);

      for(i=0; i<36; i++){
    tempDouble = *Curve[i,0];
    calFile[i,0] = tempDouble.ToString("F2");
    tempDouble = *Curve[i,1];
    calFile[i,1] = tempDouble.ToString("F0");
    tempDouble = *Curve[i,2];
    calFile[i,2] = tempDouble.ToString("F2");
    tempDouble = *Curve[i,3];
    calFile[i,3] = tempDouble.ToString("F2");


          streamOut->WriteLine( "{0}\t{1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{1}\t{1}\t{1}\t{1}\t{1}\t{1}\t{1}\t{1}",calFile[i,0], calFile[i,1], calFile[i,2],calFile[i,3] );


      }
     streamOut->Close();
   }

   catch(IOException ^)
   {

    MessageBox::Show("File Not Written\n Please Check the File\n and Try Again");

   } 




     }
```

};

```
array<double^,2> ^makeCurve(array<double^,2> ^Coef1, array<double^,2> ^Coef2, array<double^,2> ^Coef3, double Vol) { 

    array<double^,2> ^Curve = gcnew array<double^,2>(36, 4);
    array<double^,3> ^Funct = gcnew array<double^,3>(3,4,36);

             array<double^> ^LLmin = gcnew array<double^>(3);
             array<double^> ^LLmax = gcnew array<double^>(3);
             array<int^> ^Order = gcnew array<int^>(3);


             LLmin[0] = *Coef1[0,0];
             LLmin[1] = *Coef2[0,0];
             LLmin[2] = *Coef3[0,0];
             LLmax[0] = *Coef1[1,0];
             LLmax[1] = *Coef2[1,0];
             LLmax[2] = *Coef3[1,0];

             Order[0] = (int) *Coef1[2,0];
             Order[1] = (int) *Coef2[2,0];
             Order[2] = (int) *Coef3[2,0];


             double maxLLcut = 0.0;
             double minLLcut = *LLmax[0];

             for(int n=0; n<3; n++) {
                if( maxLLcut < *LLmax[n]) maxLLcut = *LLmax[n];
                if( minLLcut > *LLmax[n]) minLLcut = *LLmax[n];
             }
             int npts = 36;
             if(maxLLcut != minLLcut){
                npts = 35;

             }

             double LL = 0.05;

             double DeltaLL;
             double LLOrd = 1.0; 

             DeltaLL = minLLcut/((float) npts - 1.0);

             for(int i=1; i < npts ; i++) {
                 Curve[i,0] = LL;

                 for (int n = 0; n < 4 ; n++) {

                     // Use polynomial coefs to calculate Volume
                 LLOrd = 1.0;
                 for(int k=3; k < *Coef1[2,n]+3; k++) {
                     Funct[0,n,i] = *Funct[0,n,i] +*Coef1[k,n] * LLOrd;
                     LLOrd = LLOrd *LL;
                 }
                 LLOrd = 1.0;
                 for(int k=3; k < *Coef2[2,n]+3; k++) {
                     Funct[1,n,i] = *Funct[1,n,i] +*Coef2[k,n] * LLOrd;
                     LLOrd = LLOrd *LL;
                 }
                 LLOrd = 1.0;
                 for(int k=3; k < *Coef3[2,n]+3; k++) {
                     Funct[2,n,i] = *Funct[2,n,i] +*Coef3[k,n] * LLOrd;
                     LLOrd = LLOrd *LL;
                 }



                 }

                    double BurstPerNl = 0.0;
                    double BurstInt = 0.0;
            for(int j = 0; j<4; j++) {
                    if(*Funct[iL,j+1,i] == *Funct[iH,j+1,i]){
                        Curve[i,j+1] = *Funct[iCr,j+1,i];
                    }else{
                     BurstPerNl = (*Funct[iL,j+1,i] - *Funct[iH,j+1,i])/(*Funct[iL,0,i] - *Funct[iH,0,i]);
                     BurstInt = *Funct[iCr,1,i] - BurstPerNl * *Funct[iCr,j+1,i];

                     Curve[i,j+1] = BurstPerNl * (Vol - *Funct[iCr,0,i]) + *Funct[iCr,j+1,i];
                    }
            }
             LL = LL + DeltaLL;
        }

             if (npts < 36){

                    Curve[35,0] = maxLLcut;

                for (int l = 1; l<4; l++) {

                    Curve[35,l] = ((*Curve[34,l] - *Curve[32,l])/(*Curve[34,0] - *Curve[32,0])) *(*Curve[35,0] - *Curve[34,0]) + *Curve[34,l];
                }

             }

    return Curve;

         }

array<double^,2> ^makeCoefs(array<double^, 2> ^Data, array<double^> ^Args) { 

    array<double^> ^tempCoefs = gcnew array<double^>(MAXORDER +1);
    array<double^,2> ^Coefs = gcnew array<double^,2>(MAXORDER +4, 4);

    int Size;
    Size = Data->Length / 8;

    array<double^,2> ^tempE = gcnew array<double^,2>(Size+100,2);

    for(int k=0; k<Size; k++){
    tempE[k,0] = 0.0;
    tempE[k,1] = 0.0;
    }

    int m;
    for(int j=0; j < 4; j++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < Size; i++) {



        m = j*2;

            tempE[i,0] = (double) *Data[i,m];
            tempE[i,1] = (double) *Data[i,m+1];

                }
                int k = j+2;
                int Order = (int) *Args[k];
                tempCoefs = polyfit(tempE, Size-1, Order);

                Coefs[0,j] = *Args[0];
                Coefs[1,j] = *Args[1];
                Coefs[2,j] = *Args[j+2];

                for(int k = 0; k < *Args[j+2]; k++) {

                Coefs[3+k, j] = *tempCoefs[k];

                }

            }
            return Coefs;


       }


array<double^,2> ^fillData(int Num,  array<double^> ^Args, runData ^rawData) {

             // Create data sets to be fit based on cuts
             int j1 = 0;
             double MeasuredVolume;

             array<double^,2> ^Data = gcnew array<double^,2>(Num,8);                 
             for(int i=1; i<Num; i++) { 
                 if(*rawData->fData1[i,0] > *Args[0] && *rawData->fData1[i,0] < *Args[1]){
                 MeasuredVolume = ( *rawData->fData1[i,6])/( *rawData->iData1[i,4]);
                 if(MeasuredVolume > -1.0*MAXVOLUME && MeasuredVolume < MAXVOLUME) {



                 Data[j1,0] =  *rawData->fData1[i,0];
                 Data[j1,1] = ( *rawData->fData1[i,6])/( *rawData->iData1[i,4]);

                 Data[j1,2] =  *rawData->fData1[i,0];
                 Data[j1,3] =  *rawData->fData1[i,3];

                 Data[j1,4] =  *rawData->fData1[i,0];
                 Data[j1,5] =  *rawData->fData1[i,2];

                 Data[j1,6] =  *rawData->fData1[i,0];
                 Data[j1,7] =  *rawData->fData1[i,4];


                     j1++;

                 }
             }
             }
                j1 = j1 - 1;

             array<double^,2> ^newData = gcnew array<double^,2>(j1,8);
```

//               newData = *Data;

```
             for(int k=0; k<j1; k++){
                 for(int i = 0; i<8; i++){
                 newData[k,i] = *Data[k,i];
                 }
             }
                return newData;

}


    runData  ^LoadData(array<String^> ^ rawData)
    {



     int numLines = 0; 
     int numCols = 0;
     int indx = 0;
     int drops = 0;
     array<String^,2> ^staFile1;

      double WPcoefs[MAXORDER+1]; // [ = gcnew array<double^>(MAXORDER+1);

      numLines = rawData->Length;

      array<String^> ^Header=rawData[0]->Split(',');

      numCols = Header->Length;

      staFile1 = gcnew array<String^,2>(numLines,numCols);

    double temp_d;
    int temp_i;
    runData ^filledData = gcnew runData;
```

//       runData filledData; // = (new runData);

```
  double vol, LL, deltaV;

  for(int i=0;i<numLines;i++)
  {
    array<String^> ^lineSplit=rawData[i]->Split(',');
    for(int j=0;j<numCols;j++){
      staFile1[i,j] = lineSplit[j];

  }

if(staFile1[i,8] != "11" && staFile1[i,8] != "15") {
    if(i>0){

              filledData->fData1[indx,1] = double::Parse(staFile1[i,27]);
              filledData->fData1[indx,2] = double::Parse(staFile1[i,28]);

              filledData->fData1[indx,3] = double::Parse(staFile1[i,29]);
              array<String^> ^SptFreq = staFile1[i,31]->Split(':');
              filledData->fData1[indx,4] = double::Parse(SptFreq[0]);
              filledData->drops = (double::Parse(staFile1[i,33]));
              filledData->iData1[indx,4] =  filledData->drops;
              LL = *filledData->fData1[indx,0];

                double LLOrd = 1.0;
                vol = 0.0;
                 for(int k=0; k <= MAXORDER; k++) {
                     vol = vol + *filledData->WPcoefs[k] * LLOrd;
                     LLOrd = LLOrd * LL;
                 }


              filledData->fData1[indx,5] = vol;
              if(indx >= 1) {
                  deltaV = *filledData->fData1[indx-1,5] - *filledData->fData1[indx,5];
                  filledData->fData1[indx-1,6] = deltaV * 1000.0;
                if(*filledData->iData1[indx,4] > 0){
                double Vol = ((*filledData->fData1[indx-1,6] / *filledData->iData1[indx,4]));
                if(Vol > -1.0*MAXVOLUME && Vol < MAXVOLUME){
                 indx++;
                    }
                }
              }else{
                  indx++;
              }
        }       
    }
  }

        filledData->numLines = numLines;
        filledData->numCols = numCols;
        filledData->drops = *filledData->iData1[1,4];
        filledData->indx = indx;
        return  filledData;
    }
```

Hopefully this is enough information.

The problem is that the class instance LowE is overwritten with MedE when the button to load the second file is pushed.

Comment: You won't get any help unless you post your code or a failing test case.

Comment: Do you know what the `static` keyword does, when applied to class member data?

Comment: I know that the compiler complained that I didn't declare the array or class with a static key word. I assumed that it set a memory location for the variable. I tried to write code with out that key word and I couldn't get anything to compile.

Comment: I tried to fix the formatting of your question, but I got the following message: *Body is limited to 30000 characters; you entered 36487.* That's actually a hint you provided *way too much code* ;) Good to see you solved your problem, but for the next time try to reduce your posted code to a [minimal reproducible test case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - this'll ensure you get better help, and *faster*.

Comment: When I provided minimal code the criticism was that that there wasn't enough code and it wouldn't compile....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it turns out that the problem was with declaring the array static in the class. Apparently what I actually wanted was to declare the variable but create it in the initialization function. I had tried this earlier, but the compiler choked and I thought that there was a problem with doing it this way. But, once I was determined that this was the solution I was able to make it work. Static means that the memory is the same for all instances of the class which is a convenient way to share data common to all instances of a class. I realized that I could use this for another array in the same class that would no longer need to be read in each time.